# Is it possible to have a rule use hidden terminals?

Tags: grammar, xtext

In all my grammar rules, except for one, spaces should be hidden and not picked up by the parser.

For this single rule, it would be good if I could parse spaces, but I feel that it would be unecessary for me to stop having hidden spaces, since it would require me to start parsing spaces in every other rule.

So I am wondering if there is some way for a rule to use hidden terminals, or is there some other way of doing it? Thanks!

Comment: as far as i know you can use hidden terminal rules. where is the problem? are you not been able to use hidden terminal rules??
please elaborate your problem a little bit more if you can.

Comment: my WS terminal, which is hidden, looks like this : `terminal WS : (' '|'\t')+;` (Includes spaces and tabs). I now want to write one of my rules so that it can not include any whitespaces: `Space: '||' INT '||';`. How would I go about doing this, since my whitespaces are hidden?

Comment: try some thing like
`Model:
    content+=Element+;
Element:
    Data | Path;
Data: // white spaces allowed for parser
    name = ID ' ' INT ' ' ref=[crossref] ' '
;
`
and all other rules remain same
what it will do is, it will insure spaces between name interger and cross reference. I hope you want something like this. this is the simplest way i guess.